# Is it bad coding practice to create something in a get if it does not exist?

Tags: java, code-quality

So I have a webservice that has something like a `getAccount` where it would return an identifier to the account if it got it, else throw an exception. The client will always want to create an account if an exception is thrown with the same info the get is done with.

I am creating a convenience library for clients that will be handling all of the webservice calls inside so they don't need to know how to do the calls themselves.

What I am wondering is in this library if I were to create a `getAccount(accountName)` that will get the account if it exists, and if it does not then create it and return the info, is that a bad thing to do? Should I leave it to the client to handle the exceptions or simply name it something like getOrCreateAccount? Does it matter?

Is it bad practice to create something in a get operation?

Comment: At the very least, I would name it `getOrCreateAccount` or similar.

Comment: It seems valid in the context of lazy initialization. However, it depends if you have a need to use that pattern in your library.

Comment: I like the verb `acquire`, like `acquireAccount`. It doesn't have an existing meaning in any major protocols that I have encountered, and it has an imperative ring to it that suits it well.  "Do whatever you have to do to acquire one of these for me. Request it, build it, fake it, steal it, I don't care, just get me one or die trying."

Comment: "The client will always want to create an account" - that seems highly unusual. If I can't get the account because the user mistyped their username, I certainly don't want to create an account with the mistyped name.

Comment: According to the javabean spec http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/spec-136004.html `getSomething()` is for getters, and `setSomething()` is for setters. Imo anything that does something more intellectual must be called something else, i.e. `fetchSomething`, `obtainSomething`,  `computeSomething`, or `doSomethingElse` etc.

Comment: @ChrisC I believe that's an entirely different use-case. There's a big difference between loading/initializing some state and creating a new entity/record.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it matters. In my opinion, it's a generally a bad practice to create something in a procedure that is not documented as having the powers of creation. Either name the procedure `getOrCreate...` or have a separate `create...` procedure and then if you *really* want, have a `getOrCreate...` that first attempts `get...`, and if that fails, calls `create...` and then calls `get...`.

The user of the library will probably not expect the `get...` procedure to create if the get operation fails. If they suddenly find out that their test calls to `get...` created a whole tonne of data, they will probably be rather surprised. And how do they clean it up? What if they write code thinking that they will get an error if `get...` fails and they want to handle that *their* way?

Comment: Thanks, the create actually returns the id that the get would return too so I wouldn't have to do a `get...` `create...` `get...` just the first two. I will talk to the client about whether they will ever require the ability to simply call a `get` without wanting to create

Comment: @Mike: I still think it should have `create` in the name, just to be 100% clear about what's happening.

Comment: Yes I agree, I was planning on making it something along the lines of getOrCreate because my original thought was just to do get but I realized that it is not immediately clear that it is also creating something in the background

Comment: This is super late but `getOrCreate` has precedence in a popular web framework:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create

Answer (score 18):

No, it is not 'bad practice'.  So long as you and the other developers agree thats how you want it to work, its just fine.  After all, it'd be returning an account, which is what you want.  That the account is created 'under the hood' is irrelevant to the caller.

Comment: Only exception is if it's a publicly available API. The larger community has already agreed that GET is indempotent and nullipotent; in other words, the same action is performed each time, and it's a safe method that doesn't change the state of the server. This is in the [REST Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Aside from that, if the API just exists in your own little world, do whatever is accepted by your group.

Comment: I disagree, even for a public API its fine - so long as it *makes sense within the context* of whatever the API is supposed to do.  There's little point in creating multiple entries in the API when a single one would do the trick.

Comment: For the record it is an entirely internal library and I have the ability to just tell the team using it how it works

Comment: @jmort253: I think the service is simply named `getAccount`, it doesn't necessarily use an HTTP GET. TBH, that was my first thought, too.

Comment: @GrandmasterB - Sorry, I was thinking REST, as in HTTP API's like Google's Weather API's, etc, etc. and all that. For a code library, I agree 100% with your points. Use whatever makes the most sense. +1

Comment: @jmort253: A service is nullipotent if it has no side effects visible to the *client*.  The server can do as it pleases.

Comment: @kevincline, I guess I was thinking about it in terms of, let's say, charging my credit card. If the server charges my card based on a GET request but still gives me a result like "declined" every time I run it, that feels like it goes against the spirit of GET. With that said, I do see your point. The server could count the number of GET requests and lock me out after 3 queries, thereby rate limiting me, but without changing any details of my account. I do think that's an important distinction when one says the server state isn't modified. Perhaps I should say "client state on server" instead

Comment: @jmort253: Charging a credit card or any other action that changes the client-visible state should not happen on a GET request.

Comment: @GrandmasterB `No, it is not 'bad practice'. So long as you and the other developers agree` uhm... agreeing collectively to do something bad doesn't make it right. @Mike when in doubt, think of POLA, the German version covers your question exactly: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Least_Surprise

Comment: @Christian contrary to popular opinion, there is no objective 'correct' way to do things. Just ways people have all agreed are better for their situation. So if he and his coworkers all agree on an approach, it is, by definition not 'bad practice' even if you don't like it.

Comment: @GrandmasterB that is wrong by a long stretch. There are many ways to do something - some are better than others and some are ridiculously wrong - that's a fact, not an opinion. _Choosing an option **solely** based on least work needed_ is by definition a "bad practice" (which isn't limited to programming). Again, doing something that the rest of the world recognised as a bad idea just because your team of 3 junior devs didn't think it through doesn't make it a good practice.

Comment: As to the original question, I'd go so far as classify such behaviour (creating a new entity in a `get` call) as a bug (unexpected behaviour). Imagine asking a robot to **get** you an apple from your kitchen fruit bowl and **instead** _it takes your money to buy an orchard and apple seeds to try growing an apple tree_. That's impressive, sophisticated - but ultimately bad - behaviour.

Comment: @Christian They (as a team) did not have the same view. And since they are the ones who had to maintain it and know how was being used, their opinions on what constitutes 'least surprise' is what mattered.

Answer (score 11):

If `getAccount()` can always return an account, then from the caller's point of view, the account does exist, and has always existed.  There is no need to for `getAccount()` to 'create' anything.  The account doesn't have to be stored anywhere until it is different from the default account.

Comment: +1  Generally, `GetOrCreate` is the wrong semantic *but* getting an object which may "logically" exist whether or not it phyiscally exists is fine.  As an example, a sparse array of mutable items may not have any storage allocated for element 1,841,533, but still allow that element to be "retrieved" by creating a new object, storing it, and returning a reference.

Answer (score 4):

It makes most sense to create 3 methods:

getAccount -> Which just gets the account.

createAccount -> Creates an account.

getAccountAndCreateIfNeeded -> Choose your own naming ;)

Why separation: You have a simple method for getting and creating. That is a clear testable method for both. For getAccount it is not an exception to *not* find the account. So just return false or something like that, it is expected.

Then you can use that return value in your grouped function: getAccountAndCreateIfNeeded which is now also testable, it should return an account always. Whatever you ask.

All these 3 methods are clear, it is exactly clear what they do and what they return. You may make agreements now with your team but this kind of exceptions are terrible on the long run. Just make them very clear and you will have no issues.

Comment: Also, from Clean Code: "If your method can't do what its name implies, then throw an Exception." I'd have a Try/Catch block inside 'GetOrCreateIfneeded' that throws on a failed GET and then has the 'createAccount' inside the Throw for whatever exception type comes back for the failed get.

Comment: I might suggest a fourth method: `getAccountIfExists`, which would either get an account or indicate that it doesn't exist without creating a new one. The `getAccount` method itself should presuppose that the account exists, and throw an exception if not.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the circumstances.

For example, you can use it to do lazy loading/instantiation, deferring the loading of data or the creation of an instance until it's actually needed.  This is normally sensible as it saves resources that you might not need (if the class/data is never needed then it's never loaded).

However, in this particular case, I'd say that having a method called getAccount that would create a new account if it didn't exist would not be good practice.  If the user has given some credentials to identify a particular account and that account couldn't be found, does that mean that the user is not yet a customer and should have an account created for them, or does it mean that the credentials were mistyped and the user needs to be asked to verify that they've entered what they meant to enter?

If you have a getAccount method that does create a new account if it couldn't identify one, then you have no choice in the matter.  If you split account creation and account getting out into separate methods, then you have a lot more flexibility in deciding what to do should an attempt to get an account fails.

Comment: Related answer on lazy loading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28780824/327074

Comment: How would you name a lazy loading method?