# Boolean return of set.add() in if conditional?

Tags: java, coding-style, clean-code

The add operator of the set class returns a boolean which is true if the element (which is to be added) wasn't already there, and false otherwise. Is writing

```
if (set.add(entry)) {
    //do some more stuff
}
```

considered good style in terms of writing clean code?
I am wondering since you do two things at once. 1) adding the element and 2) checking whether the element existed.

Comment: You're talking about the standard [`java.util.Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-), which returns true on `add` when the element wasn't already there, right?

Comment: I would usually consider the opposite test: `if (!set.add(entry)) {// entry already present, possibly a case you want to handle}`

Comment: Is there something wrong with doing two things at once?

Comment: @user2357112 yes, that's right.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, it is.

The usual point of having an operation return a Boolean value is that you can use it to make decisions, i.e. within an `if` construct. The only other way you could realize this potential would be to store the return value in a variable and then immediately reuse it in an `if`, which is just silly and certainly not in any way preferable to writing `if(operation()) { ... }`. So just go ahead and do that, we won't judge you (for that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As @Niels vanReijmersdal points out in his answer doing this breaks the command and query separation, doesn't it? Don't you think that that matters?

Comment: @AndreasBraun personally I think command query separation is dumb.  It is often logical for one method to both perform an action and returning a value related to that action.  Enforcing an artificial separation between the two leads to unnecessarily verbose code.

Comment: @dan1111: indeed. Further, “command and query separation” leads to the “check then act” and similar anti patterns, which can break in multi-threaded contexts. It’s rather strange to advertise such a separation, when the rest of the world is trying to build atomic fused operations for robust and efficient SMP solutions at the same time…

Comment: @Holger: your objection is specifically addressed on page 759, plus, there is an entire chapter on an approach to safe concurrency and distribution, which is actually *derived from* the CQS principle. Do you have any specific objections to those arguments?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: page 759 of what? Since an atomic operation is intrinsically immune against the “check then act” anti-pattern, it doesn’t look beneficial to split it it up just to read an “entire chapter” of whatever to find out, how to make the construct thread safe again. Since you didn’t name any actual arguments, I have no “specific objections to those arguments”.

Comment: @Holger: I'm talking about Object-Oriented Software Construction, specifically chapter §23.1, the chapter which defines the Command-Query Separation Principle. The ultimate paragraph explicitly mentions exactly your objection, presents an argument as to why your proposed solution is not powerful enough (in particular, your proposed solution does not allow one to add two elements in an atomic manner), and offers a general solution that solves both your problem and the "add two elements in an atomic manner" problem.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Well, I’m talking about the answer on this page, discouraging using `Set.add` as single operation without naming an alternative. If the intended operation is to add a single element and find out whether it has been added, there is no need for a more powerful alternative that still complicates the operation without benefit. I hope you are aware that `Set.add` is a builtin JRE method that can be used without studying a >700 page book first.

Comment: It doesn't return a Boolean value, it returns a boolean value.

Comment: @JörgWMittag So I read chapter 23.1 of OOSC . In the paragraph _Objections_ it says “the proper O-O technique is to enable the client, after an operation on an object, to perform a query on the status, represented for example by an attribute of the object.” But if I do that I have to access the same element in the set twice (as mentioned by others). Furthermore, how can I check after the add-operation if the element existed before? If I store that information in an attribute during the add-operation,I've created an abstract side effect which also violates the  CQS principle. What am I missing?

Comment: @AndreasBraun: The literal reading of that paragraph would mean that there is a `lastItemNotAddedBecauseItAlreadyExisted` flag that you could query after having added an item. An alternative would be to simply query for existence before adding. In both of these cases, it could of course be possible that someone else mutates the collection in between. This the objection Holger was making, but Meyer says that fusing two specific operations for reasons of atomicity (like Java does) is a special case solution and that instead, the set should rather offer a way to execute *any* series of operations

Comment: … atomically. Fusing "check-and-add" into one helps you with *your* use case, but it doesn't help with, say, someone wanting to add one element depending on whether a *different* element is already in the set. Adding a way to atomically execute a series of operations, OTOH solves *both* those cases with *one* mechanism. That's the argument Meyer makes, anyway. Chapter 30 explains Meyer's thoughts on concurrency and presents the SCOOP concurrency framework of Eiffel.

Comment: @AndreasBraun: Admittedly, I toyed around with Eiffel over 20 years ago, this was when I was still a teenager and before I even learned to program in earnest. It has evolved a lot since then. E.g. I don't think SCOOP even existed back then, neither did EiffelVision. I have never written any substantial amount of Eiffel code using "modern Eiffel" (i.e. according to latest principles and using latest features). Heck, back then Eiffel still had untracked null references, while modern Eiffel has full null tracking, and null has largely been eradicated from usage.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks for your input. I think I understand the concurrency part of the discussion. What bothers me is the following: If you have an `lastItemNotAddedBecauseItAlreadyExisted` flag which is set when adding trying to add an item - in my understanding – you create an abstract side effect because you’re changing a property of the object that is accessible via a query. This cannot be the solution since it violates the CQS principle - I think? Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

I would say it isn't as clean as possible, because it forces the maintainer to either already know or look up what the return value signifies.  Does it mean the value already existed, didn't already exist, was successfully inserted?  If you don't use it a lot, you won't know, and even if you do, it's that much more mental load.

I would prefer the following:

```
boolean added = set.add(entry);

if (added) {
    //do some more stuff
}
```

Yes, a tad more verbose, but the compiler should generate pretty much the exact same bytecode, and even people who haven't used Java sets in years can follow the logic without looking anything up.

Comment: I agree that if a true return value means an add *did not* happen, further annotation would be needed to clarify it.  But I think the problem in that case would be a return value that is the opposite of convention.

Comment: [`add` returns true if the element wasn't already there, not if it was.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) (The question's wording is misleading.)

Comment: Looking up a method is less of a burden than trying to understand the original developer's intention for a redundant variable declared outside the scope where it's used.  In all modern Java IDEs, a developer can hover their mouse pointer over a method and instantly access its documentation.  Good developers do this constantly when working with any unfamiliar API.

Comment: The method still does “two things at once”, which was the OP’s concern. Besides that, I think every developer should know the fundamental APIs like `Collection.add`…

Comment: I second @Holger. If you don't know `Set.add`, you're inexperienced and you _should_ be looking these methods up to learn them and become more experienced.

Comment: Personally, rather than documenting intent with a variable that'll never be used again, I would prefer to document it by adding a short comment describing entry conditions at the top of the block.  (For example, in this case, `Set.add()` returns `true` if the element wasn't already contained within the set, returns `false` if it was, or throws an exception if it refuses to add the element.  Therefore, I would add the line `// Element successfully added.` above `// do some more stuff`.)  That's just personal preference, though, since they both serve as different kinds of comment.

Comment: `notAlreadyPresent` is not the best wording. I would use `added`, and expect reader to know why a value would not be added to a Set.

Comment: You introduced a double negative. If the value was already there `notAlreadyPresent` will be false. :S That doesn't make the code any clearer.

Comment: @JustinTime: Using comments to describe what code does is widely considered bad practice.  Your code should be self-describing.  In a code review, I would flag your example as unacceptable.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That is also a valid opinion.  The reason I dislike the "don't use comments to describe what code does" rule is that many people misinterpret it as meaning that they should add more code for the explicit purpose of using that code as a comment, and thus violate the spirit of the rule while honouring the letter.  `boolean added = set.add(entry); if (added) // ...` is, IMO, guilty of this; it adds a variable for the explicit purpose of using that variable's name to comment on when the code block is entered, thus making it functionally identical to an actual comment.

Comment: When it comes down to using a comment that affects the code, or one that doesn't affect the code, I would prefer to use one that doesn't affect the code, hence preferring the comment-comment to the variable-name-comment.  [Note that I don't disagree with the concept of self-documenting code in general.  I merely disagree with the common interpretation that "self-documenting code" means that comments should be turned into lines of actual code instead of being left as comments, when the code is already self-explanatory to those that understand it.]

Comment: Code isn't some gauntlet where only the worthy shall pass.  You want to make the road as smooth as possible for those that follow.  Code shouldn't be written to force maintainers to make what you deem to be some sort of minimum acceptable effort in order to be able to read it.  "You *should* look these up to become more experienced."  That's okay advice for improving oneself, but the most idiotic excuse I've ever heard about code readability.  Experience makes it *much more difficult* to rely on memory for this sort of thing.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I didn't know what the return value was because I regularly use 4 different languages that do set adds 3 different ways, and Java's way isn't one of them.  I've learned and forgotten Java's way several times over my career.  Don't write code that makes you feel smarter than the next guy, write code that makes the next guy feel like they're not even reading code.

Comment: Then you should never use any class or method in the standard library, or any other library, because someone might have to look up what it does.

Comment: Yes, because striving to write code that minimizes the need for lookup is [totally the same thing](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman) as never looking up anything at all.

Answer (score 9):

**If true means success, then it's good, clear code.**

There is a widespread convention that a function or method returns true (or something that evaluates to true) on success.  As long as your code follows that, I think putting the method in the conditional is fine.

Code like this is unnecessarily cluttered in my view:

```
boolean frobulate_succeeded = thing.frobulate();

if (frobulate_succeeded) {
    ...
}
```

It feels like you are repeating yourself.

However, the question is ambiguous on the meaning of the return value.  You say "a boolean which indicates whether the added element already existed", which might imply that true means the element existed (and add did not occur).  If that is the case, I would ideally change the method's return behavior to be more conventional.  If that isn't possible, I would add an extra intermediate variable that allows you to clearly label the return result in your code (as suggested by others).

Comment: What does success mean in the context of adding an item to a set? Not throwing an exception means success; true vs. false means something more specific in this context.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret In this case, an exception means the set refused to add the element, `false` means that the element wasn't added because it was already contained, and `true` means the element wasn't already contained.  As `add()` adds the element to the set if the set didn't already contain it, `true` therefore means that the element was successfully added to the set.

Comment: @JustinTime You are adding your own value judgements to the two cases. Another interpretation is that success is that the item is in the set when the method returns. If the item was already in the set, `add` succeeds without having to do anything. If the item wasn't already in the set, `add` succeeds by adding the item to the set. Which interpretation is correct is arbitrary. The less arbitrary definition of success is the one from the language: the method succeeds if it returns normally.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I'm using the method's own value judgment, as documented by its name: it considers success to be successfully _adding_ the element.  If a set is only capable of containing one copy of any given element, and the specified element is already in the set, then _adding_ the item cannot succeed.  In this case, returning normally is a guarantee that the set contains the element, and the return value is an indication of whether the method completed the task it claims to do (in this case, whether it added the element during that specific call).

Comment: The least arbitrary definition of success is that the method successfully performed the task it set out to perform.  If I have a method `firstLessThanSecond(int l, int r)`, and it returns `true` if `l > r` or `false` if `l <= r`, then that method is _not_ successful, even though it returns normally.

Comment: @JustinTime `add` is a severe abbreviation of the contract. The documentation starts with "Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present", which is satisfied whether or not the item was already in the set. You are free to interpret the return value however you want but ultimately it is just your interpretation. And in your second example the method evaluates whether a condition is true. If the condition is false the method certainly has not failed, as it has successfully evaluated the conditional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56761/discussion-between-solomonoffs-secret-and-justin-time).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's very C-like. Most of the time I would prefer to have a descriptively-named variable for a mutation result, and no mutation happening in an `if` condition.

A compiler will eliminate this variable if it's immediately reused. A human will have easier time reading the source; to me, it's more important.

Should somebody have to extend the condition by adding an `and` / `or` clause to the if condition, they may end up not calling `.add()` in certain cases due to short-circuit evaluation. Unless short-circuiting is specifically anticipated, this may end up as a bug.

Comment: If I write `if (set.contains(entry)){set.add(entry); //do more stuff}` is that also eliminated by the compiler?

Comment: @AndreasBraun: I don't think so; the compiler has no idea about the semantic link between `contains` and `add`. Also, it does double work of looking up `entry` in the set; this may play a role for very large sets and very light loops.

Comment: So I take it you would rather not write `if (set.contains(entry)){set.add(entry); //do more stuff}` but instead go with e.g. Karl Bielefeldt's answer?

Comment: @AndreasBraun: exactly (upvoted that answer).

Comment: a good point. Mutations in ifs are tricky, as a future dev may had other conditions with short-circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to break [Command Query Separation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html). This is discussed in the [Clean Code book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) and the [Function Structure](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-4/show) video. So from a Clean Code perspective I think it is not considered good style.

> “Clean code is simple and direct. Clean code reads like well-written
>   prose. Clean code never obscures the designer’s intent but rather is
>   full of crisp abstractions and straightforward lines of control.
>
> -- Grady Booch author of Object Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications”

For me the intent of your code is unclear. Is the if both executed when the entry is added succesful, or also when it already exists? What does `add()` return? the item? The error-code?

Comment: Well, yes that's what I thought as well. But I also think @Kilian Foth has a point. If I wanted to seperate query  and command I would have to write `if (set.contains(entry)){set.add(entry); //do more stuff}` which seems kind of silly. What's your take on this?

Comment: I don't know the domain and context of this code to suggest a good name, but I would wrap this in a function with clear intent. For example: doesEntryExistOrCreateEntry(entry), this could contain your contains() + add() logic and return a boolean. Similar question here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149708/is-it-bad-coding-practice-to-create-something-in-a-get-if-it-does-not-exist which discusses this practise outside of clean code.

Comment: I think the command query separation rule is dumb, particularly when applied to a case like this, where a method both performs an action and returns the success state of the action.  But also, you don't explain what the rule is or provide much in the way of justification for it.  Downvoted for these reasons.

Comment: Command and query both must locate the item in the set, which requires twice the computation to do separately.

Comment: "What does add() return?" I expect any java developer who does code review to know the `Collection` api.

Comment: Agreed with @dan1111. It's *especially* dumb because it is the sort of things that makes fertile ground for race conditions.